# Jwplayer not play m3u8 file?

Tags: jwplayer, m3u8

my jwplayer cant play m3u8 file
Error loading player: No playable sources found
what am i doing?

version 7.4.2
http://hamrahna.com/videos/ifilm

Comment: are you using jwplayer premium key? It's needed for hls streaming

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Take some time to read over [ask] to improve your question and increase your chances of getting an answer to your problem. At a minimum, please provide specific context to your error and what you have attempted to solve the issue yourself.

Comment: If you need a free player, get videojs with videojs-hls plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your player setup should look like this:

```
   jwplayer('container').setup ({
        file: 'https://569888080fa01.streamlock.net/live/jelly.stream/playlist.m3u8'
    });
```

Here is a demo of the player loading an m3u8 file: https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-player/demos/toolbox/live-streaming/

A premium license is required for HLS streaming.